# Determinar o tempo da execução da próxima tarefa com base no fim da execução atual em aplicação Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, timer, windows-service

Eis o meu problema. Tenho uma aplicação como serviço do windows que precisa ser executada 15 segundos depois que a execução atual da tarefa for terminada.

A tarefa basicamente realiza operações no banco de dados e pode ser que a execução leve mais que 15 segundos, daí o problema.

Meu código para determinar o intervalo de execução esta assim:

```
worker = new Timer(new TimerCallback(saveFiles), null, 0, interval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só fazer a aplicação esperar um pouco antes de executar a operação novamente.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// outras coisas

public static async void saveFiles()
{
    // Fazer um monte de coisa demorada

    await Task.Delay(15000);
    saveFiles();
}
```

Ou

```
while(true)
{
    saveFiles();
    await Task.Delay(15000);
}
```